# $ \mathcal{R}"\bigcap{\mathcal{A}} = \bigcap \{\mathcal{R}"A : A \in \mathcal{A} \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a non-empty family of sets, and $\mathcal{R}$ is a binary relation then
$$ \mathcal{R}"\bigcap{\mathcal{A}} = \bigcap \{\mathcal{R}"A : A \in \mathcal{A} \}.$$

**Proof.**

$ \subseteq |$

Let $y \in \mathcal{R}"\bigcap{\mathcal{A}}.$ Entonces, como $\mathcal{A} \neq \emptyset,$ then $\bigcap{\mathcal{A}}$ is well defined, and by definition of direct image, $y \in \mathcal{R}"\bigcap{\mathcal{A}} \Rightarrow \exists x \in \bigcap\mathcal{A}$ $\land$ $yRx.$

If $x \in \bigcap\mathcal{A},$ then $x \in A$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}.$

$\rightarrow$ $ y \in ImR$ and $x \in A$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $xRy.$ This is precisely the direct image of $A,$ under $R:$

$R"[A] = \{ y \in ImR : \exists x \in A (yRx) \}.$ Meaning

$y \in R"[A]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}.$

$\supseteq |$

Let $y \in \bigcap \{\mathcal{R}"A : A \in \mathcal{A} \}.$ Then, $y \in \{\mathcal{R}"A : A \in \mathcal{A} \}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}.$

If $y \in R''[A] ,$ then $\exists x \in A (yRx)$ $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}.$

$\rightarrow x \in \mathcal{A}$

$\rightarrow y \in ImR$ and $ x \in \bigcap\mathcal{A}$ and $xRy.$

$\rightarrow y \in R"\bigcap\mathcal{A}.$

The proof is wrong. I don't see why...

Comment: What does $\mathcal{R}"A$ means? What are the domain and codomain of $\mathcal{R}$?

Comment: The proof has to be wrong because the result is false. Let $\mathcal A=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ and let $R$ be the relation that relates each of 1 and 2 to 3 (and nothing else). Then the left side of your equation is empty (because $\bigcap\mathcal A=\varnothing$) but the right side contains 3.

Comment: *Por favor*, don't mix *español* and *inglés*!

Comment: It means direct image, and the domain would be $\bigcap\mathcal{A}$ the image would be the intersection of $R"[A_i]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a relation $R \subseteq A \times B$, $S \subseteq A$ we define
$$
R(S) := \{y\in{}B:\exists{}x\in{}S\text{ with }(x,y)\in{}R\}
$$

If I understand correctly, you have a family of sets $\mathcal{A}=\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ with $I\neq\emptyset$, sets $A$ and $B$ and a relation $R\subseteq{}A\times{}B$ with $\forall i \in I, A_i \subseteq A$.

Assuming $A=\bigcap_i A_i$, you want to prove that $R(\bigcap_i A_i)=\bigcap_i R(A_i)$.

Proof:

(1) $R(\bigcap_i A_i) \subseteq \bigcap_i R(A_i)$

Suppose $y \in R(\bigcap_i A_i)$. Then $\exists x \in \bigcap_i A_i \text{ with }(x,y)\in{}R$. Since $\forall i \in I$, $x \in A_i$, we have that $\forall i \in I$, $y \in R(A_i)$, i.e. $y \in \bigcap_i R(A_i)$.

(2) $\bigcap_i R(A_i) \subseteq R(\bigcap_i A_i)$

Suppose $y \in \bigcap_i R(A_i)$. Then $\forall i \in I$, $y \in R(A_i)$. Let $j \in I$. There exists $x \in A_j \text{ with }(x,y)\in{}R$. Hence $y \in R(A)$. Since $A=\bigcap_i A_i$, $y \in R(\bigcap_i A_i)$.

Q.E.D.

Note that if your assumption is false, i.e. $\bigcap_i A_i \subsetneq A$, point (2) is generally false.